# webview2 server certificate custom validation

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

I have a Winforms application with an embedded webview2 control connecting to an embedded device with a self-signed TLS certificate.

I am trying to find a way to do server certificate custom validation and I cannot find any webview2 property or event that looks like it offers this.  I am using setIgnoreCertificateErrors but this is not what I want, I want something similar to ServerCertificateCustomValidation from System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: IFAIK, that feature is not part of the accessible implementation. You have a way to *partially* handle Client Certificate validation, it (IIRC) should be part of the `ICoreWebView2Experimental3` interface, not directly available in .Net. In C++, you need the WebView2 SDK and the [Windows Implementation Libraries (WIL)](https://github.com/Microsoft/wil). -- Check the [C++ sample code](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples) to see what's available at this time.

Comment: I found that for client cert selection, but could not see anything for the server cert. I think EO.WebBrowser and CefSharp both support this.  Perhaps another browser control is the only way.

Comment: Simply install the self signed certificate on the computer's trusted root certificate. Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks @PoulBak but I have other constraints.  I need custom validation or I need a different browser control that has it.